# Run TELNET commands in a batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Hi I am using the below TELNET command in a batch file email.bat. But when I run the batch I am getting the message

"220 edcmsgmra02.domain.com ESMTP Sun, 27 Dec 2015 07:00:18 -0500"

If I run each and every line manually the command is working. Can you please help me run the below command in a single batch.

```
TELNET edcsmtp.emea.domain.com 25

HELO emea.domain.com 

mail from: admin@domain.com 

rcpt to: Vijayn@domain.com 

data 
SUBJECT: Stock File Alert!!!!!

File is not received in the directory. Kindly place the files to process
.
QUIT
```

Comment: You can't do it this way.  You may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601579/how-to-automate-a-telnet-session-without-sendkeys

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to script the Windows telnet client. You can use [VBS with SendKeys](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/automate-telnet-commands-vb-script/) to control the client or use a [third party telnet scripting tool](http://ss64.com/nt/telnet.html), but there is no way to send commands to it directly.

If you just want to send an email alert, try [SendEmail](http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/). SendEmail is a lightweight, command line SMTP email client. Simple to use and feature rich.